# Customising the DatePicker Dialog Android

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog

I am using a DatePicker in a Dialog box to allow the user to chose a date. But I just want them to chose a month and a day. Is there any way I can make the year **not** show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way to do so in the [Javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html). You could create your own using NumberPicker (which unfortunately is not in an externally available API, but the sourcecode is readily available).  See http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5 for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I will have to use a number picker but I would be nice to be able to customise the Date Picker like that. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: I agree- would be nice if you could customize it.  They really need to open up the widget API